# Sort Django query result by number of matches

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my Django app, I have `Blog`s and `BlogPosts`.

Their models are basically this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(Entry)
    details = models.TextField()
    ...

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    title = models.CharField()
    ...
```

Given a list of blog names, I would like to return all of the `BlogPost`s that appear in at least one of the given blogs.

I've figured out how to do this using `Q` objects. I've created a query like this:

```
# Return blogs that appear in either nameOfBlog1 or nameOfBlog2
q1 = Q(blog__name = nameOfBlog1)
q2 = Q(blog__name = nameOfBlog2)
Blog.objects.filter(q1 | q2)
```

This works.

However, I would like to receive the results in the order of the `BlogPost`s that match the highest number of `Blog`s. So for example, the `BlogPost`s that appear in all of the `Blog`s I'm searching against, should appear first in the list, while `BlogPost`s that only appear in one of the `Blog`s should appear at the end.

Is there any way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
BlogPost.objects.filter(q1 | q2).annotate(blog_times=Count('id')).order_by('blog_times')
```

Comment: What is `id`? Do you mean `name`?

Comment: you can put 'name' ,and  'id' is field added automatically for your models  ,see this link for more information about 'id'  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#quick-example